Derivative in recurrence relation of Slevinsky's formula for derivatives of function composition
I'm working on an efficient Taylor series solution to an ODE along the lines of
$$ \vec{y}'(t) = f(\vec{y}(t)) $$
Differentiation of the equation gives
$$ y^{(k+1)} = \frac{\partial^k f(y(t))}{\partial t^k} $$
which I expanded with Hoppe's formula,
$$ f(y(t))^{(k)} = \sum_{i = 1}^k A^i_k(t)f^{(i)}(y(t))$$
with
$$ A^i_k(t) = \sum_{j = 1}^i \frac{(-1)^{i-j}}{j!(i-j)!} y(t)^{i-j} (y(t)^j)^{(k)} $$
According to Slevinsky (2009), higher derivatives can efficiently be computed due to the fact that $A_{m, k}$ satisfy the recursion
$$ A^i_k(t) = \frac{d}{dt}A^i_{k-1}(t) + y' A^{i-1}_{k-1}(t)$$
but I can't figure out how to efficiently calculate $\frac{d}{dt} A^i_{k-1}(t)$.
I only need to calculate $f(y(0))^{(k)}$ for my Taylor series expansion, so I'd like to simply recursively calculate the values of $A^i_k(0)$. The problem is that knowing $A^i_k(0)$ gives me no information about $A'^i_k(0)$.
I could symbolically calculate each derivative, but that defeats the purpose of the recursion.
How can I efficiently calculate $\frac{d}{dt}A^i_k(t)?$
Other methods of efficiently computing (/approximating) higher derivatives of function compositions would also be extremely helpful!

I'm not sure what is Hoppe's formula, but there is Faa di Bruno's formula, which expresses a high-order derivative of a function composition in term of Bell polynomials, for which a few different recurrences and explicit expressions are known.
